# tf.layers.batch_normalization() gamma does not exist error when trained on multiple GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, multi-gpu, batch-normalization

When I train Neural network on multiple GPU the batch normalization is not working, I use tf.layers.batch_normalization(), but when I run, I get following error:

ValueError: Variable batch_normalization_4/gamma does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

The training variables are shared with no problem, my code can run without using normalization layer, however, when I add it back, I got this error. Looks like the gamma parameter for tf.layers.batch_normalization() is not created with tf.get_variable(), someone can help?

You can find my code [HERE](https://github.com/boyuanf/tensorflow_train_multi_gpu_AWS/blob/master/multi_gpu.py), I may commented out the normalization, but you can undo it as you need.

The full error is:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-137:~/Boyuan/MultiGPU$ python multi_gpu.py --num_gpus=2
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:962: UserWarning: Duplicate key in file "/home/ubuntu/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc", line #2
  (fname, cnt))
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:962: UserWarning: Duplicate key in file "/home/ubuntu/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc", line #3
  (fname, cnt))
Reading /home/ubuntu/Boyuan/MNIST_Dataset/mnist_train.tfrecords
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_gpu.py", line 323, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "multi_gpu.py", line 320, in main
    train()
  File "multi_gpu.py", line 221, in train
    loss, correct = tower_loss(scope, images_batch, labels_batch)
  File "multi_gpu.py", line 92, in tower_loss
    logits = forward_propagation(images, layer_hidden_nums, True)
  File "multi_gpu.py", line 56, in forward_propagation
    Z_nor = tf.layers.batch_normalization(Z, training=training, momentum=0.9)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 774, in batch_normalization
    return layer.apply(inputs, training=training)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 762, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 636, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 277, in build
    trainable=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 504, in add_variable
    partitioner=partitioner)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1262, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1097, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 435, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 404, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 761, in _get_single_variable
    "reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?" % name)
ValueError: Variable batch_normalization_4/gamma does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Sure, I add the error in the question, thank you

Comment: gamma is created with get_variable, so this shouldn't happen

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree with you, however, this is what I got, if I remove the normalization, the code just works.